# Specify function

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following function. It calculates the euclidean distances form some financial figures between companies and give me the closest company. Unfortunately, sometimes the closest company is the same company. Does anyone know how I can adjust the function so that it does not return the same company?

```
#Calculating the closest distances

records = df_ipos.to_dict('records') #converting dataframe to a list of dictionaries

def return_closest(df,inp_record):
    """returns the closest euclidean distanced record"""
    
    filtered_records = df.to_dict('records')#converting dataframe to a list of dictionaries

    for record in filtered_records: #iterating through dictionaries

        params = ['z_SA','z_LEV','z_AT', 'z_PM', 'z_RG']#parameters  to calculate euclidean distance
        distance = []
        for param in params:
            d1,d2 = record.get(param,0),inp_record.get(param,0) # fetching value of these parameters. default is0 if not found
            if d1!=d1:  #checking isNan
                d1 = 0
            if d2!=d2:
                d2 = 0
            distance.append((d1 - d2)**2)
        euclidean = math.sqrt(sum(distance))
        record['Euclidean distance'] = round(euclidean,6) #assigning to a new key 
        
    distance_records = sorted(filtered_records,key = lambda x:x['Euclidean distance']) #sorting in increasing order
    
    return next(filter(lambda x:x['Euclidean distance'],distance_records),None) #returning the lowest value which is not zero. Default None

for record in records:

    ipo_year = record.get('IPO Year')
    sic_code = record.get('SIC-Code')

    df = df_fundamentals[df_fundamentals['Year']==ipo_year]
    df = df[df['SIC-Code']==sic_code] #filtering dataframe

    closest_record = return_closest(df,record)
    if closest_record:
        record['Closest Company'] = closest_record.get('Name')  #adding new columns
        record['Actual Distance'] = closest_record.get('Euclidean distance')

df_dist = pd.DataFrame(records) #changing list of dictionaries back to dataframe
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, it is not exactly clear to me what your inputs are.
But as a simple fix, I would suggest you check before your function's for loop, whether the record you are comparing is identical to the one which you check against, i.e., add:

```
...

filtered_records = [rec for rec in filtered_records if rec['Name'] != inp_record['Name']]

for record in filtered_records: #iterating through dictionaries
    ...
```

This only applies, if 'Name' really contains the company name. Also for your function not to work, there seems to be an absolute distance greater zero when comparing your parameters. I am not sure if this is intended, maybe you look at data from different years? I cannot really tell, due to the limited amount of information.

Comment: I don't really get your point with the absolute distance greater zero? How does that refers to different years?

Comment: What I mean is, if it was exactly the same company with the same parameters, then your code should filter out this record and NOT return the same company. But I don't know your data, so if this answer did not help, maybe provide same data examples.